# Intermittent SMB connection failure from Windows 11 to macOS Monterey/Ventura

Tags: samba, windows-11

I have a LAN with a TP-Link router (AXE5400, 3 months old), a Mac Mini as SMB/CIFS file-server (2020, macOS Ventura 13.2.1), and Windows 11 Laptop and a Macbook Pro laptop (c. 2020/2022). The file-server was recently upgraded from Monterey, with the problem occuring both before and after the upgrade. I also had the same problem on a TP-Link Archer C5.

UDP/TCP is fine - I can ping, do HTTP web requests, and VNC to the fileserver without any issues.

The problem occurs frequently when the laptop is on WiFi. It behaves much better when the laptop is on ethernet. I'm not sure if I ever get the problem over ethernet.

Both the Windows and Macbook Pro laptops are regularly failing to connect to the file-server's network shares for periods of time, and then work normally at other times. The attached screenshots show a simultaneous packet capture on my Windows Laptop and on the fileserver while in the middle of problems.

I'm new to packet analysis, but I see that a normal connection starts with SMB Negotiate Protocol Request, followed by SMB2 Negotiate Protocol Response from the file server, and then everything should kick off in a flurry of activity. In contrast, when the problems occur they seem to proceed as follows:

1. A TCP connection is established, which is successfully ACKd by the file server.
2. Laptop sends SMB Negotiate Protocol Request
3. Fileserver gets impatient and sends a QUIC message (presumably a red herring)
4. Fileserver sends ICMP Port unreachable
5. Eventually Laptop times out and does a RST

Any ideas what's going on? I've tried disabling wirewalls on my Laptop, my fileserver, and the TP-Link router but nothing seems to make any difference.

Wireshark on Windows Laptop, WiFi (192.168.0.92 aka IntelCor_bc:f3:36):
[image]

Wireshark on Fileserver, Ethernet (192.168.0.41 aka Rambo.local aka Apple_e7:ca:08):
[image]

Comment: UPDATE: Turns out it's related to the smbd service no longer responding to requests. Will post a formal answer once I know more.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem is with the `smbd` service that acts as the SMB server on the mac. It had just stopped responding to traffic, even though the process was still technically alive (was included in a `ps` listing).

Packet analysis on both client and server showed that, at an TCP/IP level, all packets that were sent were received. Over various runs I saw the following variations:

- SMB1 Negotiate Protocol Request being received by the server, but not responded to.
- SMB2 Negotiate Protocol Request being received by the server, but not responded to.
- SMB2 Negotiate Protocol Request received, responded to, but then a subsequent SMB Session Setup Request received by the server was not responded to.

Restarting the smbd service fixes the problem temporarily.
I'm still looking into what its underlying problem is.

---

The ICMP Port unreachable thing was a red-herring. It was in response to the QUIC packet. The QUIC packet was sent to port 443, and the mac's TCP/IP layer was just responding that nothing's listening on that port. I still think the QUIC packet was sent by the client due to impatience - perhaps it was falling back to an HTTP mode because SMB was failing.